# How to properly change what composer or Symfony2 does after running 'composer update/install'?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

There are some scripts that are executed after I run composer.

The problem is that they do things that I don't want, like `php assets:install` (without --symlink).

So I need to either be able to remove that, or add my own script to do `php assets:install --symlink`.

What would be the correct way for doing this?

**EDIT**

In `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets()` I can see an option for symlink:

```
if ($options['symfony-assets-install'] == 'symlink') {
    $symlink = '--symlink ';
```

Is that configurable somewhere?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To install assets with symlinks edit your composer.json (at the end) in this way

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
}
```

Then run composer as uusal.

Answer (score 6):

If you use composer to deploy to production environments, you may want to set the environment variable `SYMFONY_ASSETS_INSTALL` to `symlink` instead.  This way production still uses hard copies which is the recommended option.

Comment: I had to do both `SYMFONY_ASSETS_INSTALL=symlink` **and** `export SYMFONY_ASSETS_INSTALL` in my `.profile` file to get this working.