# How to share CSS and JS between bundles

Tags: javascript, css, symfony

I would create a CoreBundle, and use this for your template layout, base template, etc.. and do your includes there.

Furthermore if you leave it in the app/Resources making a new directory for Public/css to my knowledge it wont get pulled down when you install/dump your assets to the /Web directory.  So if by chance you happen to be only using those files on your live production server, and or like to use that directory as your normal include path, then it just makes more sense.

Also, for me, i use less, and the less files arent compiling and shipping the compiled version into the /web folder either.

If you make a core bundle, you can have all this natively, and have your files in an area that your more likely to be used to getting into with your file editors.

It also helps separate custom files away from the core framework better.

As a sidenote, i did like fsehat's suggestion, however i was a bit disappointed when the assets werent being handled properly.  also i dont like using ../ in include paths, ./ is ok, but not ../

if you put them in a bundle (/Your/Bundle/Public/css), after compiling, you can just call them from your templates like this for e.g. `<link href="{{ asset('/css/loader.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Possible dublicate of [Symfony 2 - Working with assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931127/symfony-2-working-with-assets).

For example, You need to store your styles in `src/YourBundle/Resources/public/css`

Use next command for assets CSS

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

Styles will be copy to `web/bundles/YourBundle/css` dir. And now you can asset them easy in templates

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate, then comment and vote/flag to close the question, but don't post an answer which doesn't do much more than linking to another question.

Comment: Thanks, I added more answer

Answer (score 0):

Put your css js in web folder like **directory**

```
C:\wamp\www\yourProject\web\bundles\acmedemo\css\
```

And use it using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/css/mystyle.css') }}" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You will share your javascripts and stylesheets between your bundles, you need to visit following URL and follow the step:

[With Assetic / Twig / Symfony2, can I define front end libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830129/with-assetic-twig-symfony2-can-i-define-front-end-libraries)

[Symfony2: How to share js libs and css between bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192568/symfony2-how-to-share-js-libs-and-css-between-bundles)