# Symfony3 & Assetic : different behavior in dev or prod

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

I'm working on Symfony 3.4 and Assetic.
Let's say my website is www.mycompany.com and i'm using 2 particular types of asset :

- Google web font via @Import() in my main CSS file
- Custom CSS fonts, with font files manually uploaded in in web/fonts/

When i visit my website in dev mode www.mycompany.com/app_dev.php/ :

- Google fonts are well loaded and work.
- Font awesome doesn't work (beacause app_dev.php/fonts/ is 404)

When i visit my website in prod mode www.mycompany.com/ :

- Google fonts doesn't work (@import seems not to be loaded...)
- Font awesome work (because css files are found in www.mycompany.com/fonts/)

Why this behavior ? For your information, i use Assetic this way to load myu assets :

```
{% stylesheets '@PimInterfaceBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

// Same for JS
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please check if you enviroment is correct try dumping or printing your enviroment variable on prod and in dev enviroments and tell me if is the correct value

Comment: Hi @JassonRojas, how to var_dump environnements variable ?

Comment: Hi @paolito75 you can use {{ app.environment }} in twig template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the cssrewrite filter, don't refer to your CSS files using the **@XxBundle** syntax.

try this

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/piminterface/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

here is doc

1. [Including CSS Stylesheets](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets)
2. [Fixing CSS Paths with the cssrewrite Filter](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter)
3. [Dumping Asset Files in the prod Environment](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment)

if this is not working for you then try `php bin/console asset:install`

in prod `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`
`

Comment: Hi @habibun, it doesn't work neither. I made your edit, then asset:install : all seem fine but Asetic doesn't generate anymore <link> tags to my css and <script> tags to my JS. I check : web/bundles/piminterface is a symlink to my src/MyCompany/PimInterfaceBundle/Resources/public .... i don't understand !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931127/symfony-2-working-with-assets